# RoR model.where() using pg array type

Tags: sql, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I stumbled on the idea of limiting my tables and associations by using arrays in my models [like so](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/).

I'm working on a task assignment app where the user will, in essence, construct a sentence to perform an action. I'm using keywords to help structure the boundaries of the sentence.

Examples include (keywords in brackets):

- "[I will] paint the fence" <- makes a new task, assigned to current_user
- "[Ask] Huck [to] paint the fence" <- find_or_create task, assign to find_or_create user
- "[Archive] painting the fence" <- soft-delete task

So here's my migration:

```
class CreateKeywords < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :keywords do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.text :pre, array: true, default: []
      t.text :post, array: true, default: []
      t.string :method, null: false, default: "read" # a CRUD indicator
    end
  end
end
```

`keyword.post` indicates what models could follow the keyword

`keyword.pre` indicates what models could preceed the keyword

My seed data looks like this:

```
Keyword.create([
  { name: "i will", post: ["task"] },
  { name: "ask", post: ["user"] },
  { name: "assign", post: ["user", "task"] },
  { name: "find a", post: ["user", "task"] },
  { name: "make a new", post: ["user", "task"], method: "create" },
  { name: "finalize", post: ["task"] },
  { name: "archive", post: ["user", "task"], method: "delete" },
  { name: "update", post: ["user", "task"], method: "update" },
  { name: "for", post: ["user", "task"], pre: ["user", "task"] },
  { name: "to", post: ["user", "task"], pre: ["user", "task"] },
  { name: "and repeat", pre: ["task"] },
  { name: "before", pre: ["task"] },
  { name: "after", pre: ["task"] },
  { name: "on", pre: ["task"] }
])
```

Now I want to do things like:

`key = Keyword.third`

`Keyword.where(pre: key.post)`

But this returns exact matches and I want to do something like:

"Return all keywords where any value of `key.post` can be found in `Keyword.pre`"

I haven't had any luck along these lines:
`Keyword.where(pre.include? key.post)`

I can iterate over all the Keywords and use AND:

```
results = []
Keyword.all.each do |k|
  comb = k.pre & key.post
  if comb.present?
    results << k
  end
end
results.map { |k| k.name }
```

But this feels bad.

And I'm a bit out of my depth on the SQL necessary to do this.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you want to know about:

1. PostgreSQL's ["array constructor" syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) which looks like `array['a', 'b', 'c']` rather than the more common `'{a,b,c}'` syntax.
2. PostgreSQL's [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT).

Array constructor syntax is convenient because when ActiveRecord sees an array as the value for a placeholder, it expands the array as a comma delimited list which works equally well with `x in (?)` and `x && array[?]`.

For the operator to use, you want:

> all keywords where any value of `key.post` can be found in `Keyword.pre`

which is another way of saying that `key.post` and `Keyword.pre` overlap and the operator for that is `&&`. There are also subset (`<@`) and superset (`@>`) operators if you need slightly different logic.

Putting that together:

```
Keyword.where('pre && array[?]', key.post)
```

or:

```
Keyword.where('pre && array[:post]', post: key.post)
```

[lacostenycoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625433/lacostenycoder), in the comments, is right to be concerned empty arrays. ActiveRecord expands empty arrays to a single `null` when filling in a placeholder so you could end up doing SQL like:

```
pre && array[null]
```

and PostgreSQL won't be able to determine the type of `array[null]`. You can include a cast:

```
Keyword.where('pre && array[:post]::text[]', post: key.post)
# --------------------------------^^^^^^^^ tell PostgreSQL that this is an array of text
```

But, since `pre && array[null]::text[]` will never be true, you could just skip the whole thing if `key.post.empty?`.

Empty arrays don't overlap with any other array (not even another empty array) so you don't need to worry about empty arrays beyond what ActiveRecord will do with them. Similarly for `pre is null`, `null && any_array` will never be true (it will actually evaluate to `null`) so there won't be any overlaps with such things.

Comment: Your first method doesn't work. The 2nd one returns items where `post: []` and I don't think that's what the question calls for.

Comment: @lacostenycoder The first and second methods are functionally identical (except for the missing single quote typo). The OP was using `Keyword.where(pre: key.post)` as an example so these will work when they have a `key` in hand already.

Comment: Thanks for the update on empty arrays, it was a problem I was already dealing with in the loop, so I feel comfortable with your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually much easier that you would expect:

```
Keyword.where("pre && post")

# testing vs your seed data plus a few I added returns:

#Keyword Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords" WHERE (pre && post)
#[<Keyword:0x007fc03c0438b0 id: 9, name: "for", pre: ["user", "task"], post: ["user", "task"], method: "read">,
 #<Keyword:0x007fc03c0435b8 id: 10, name: "to", pre: ["user", "task"], post: ["user", "task"], method: "read">,
 #<Keyword:0x007fc03c043248 id: 15, name: "foo", pre: ["bar", "baz"], post: ["baz", "boo"], method: "read">,
 #<Keyword:0x007fc03c042f28 id: 16, name: "rock", pre: ["anthem"], post: ["ballad", "anthem"], method: "read">,
 #<Keyword:0x007fc03c042cf8 id: 17, name: "disco", pre: ["mood"], post: ["ballad", "anthem", "mood"], method: "read">]
```

Comment: This would be great if I was trying to compare the `.pre` and `.post` on the same record, but I'm trying to compare a selected record with the rest of the data set. So @mu got the gist.